# Batch file, wildcard in folderpath, no idea what the wildcard can be

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wildcard

I have a batch file that attempts to replaces a file in

```
C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*\Data\Config
```

But the * varies from computer to computer, so it's not as if I can have an input list

This batch file is executed in another batch file, which is called from command-line.

Here is the batch file with the * path, **C:\script.bat**

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*\Data\Config\SyLink.xm_" del /Q "C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*\Data\Config\SyLink.xm_"
ren "C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*\Data\Config\SyLink.xml" sylink.xm_bak
del /Q "C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*\Data\Config\SyLink.xml"

echo.
echo Copying new SyLink.xml
echo.
copy C:\SyLink.xml "C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*\Data\Config"


echo.
echo Deleting temp files
del /Q "c:\SyLink.xml"
```

And this is another batch file, **C:\copy.bat** that calls the first one, i.e. C:\script.bat

```
xcopy C:\sylink.xml \\10.10.10.10\c$
xcopy C:\sylink.xml \\10.10.10.11\c$
D:\pstools\psexec.exe @C:\clients.txt -c C:\Script.bat
```

**C:\clients.txt**

```
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.11
```

Batch file is executed through the command-line

```
C:\> C:\copy.bat
```

Question is, how do I make this batch file work so it recognizes * as a wildcard?

Thanks

Comment: please ask a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for /d %%a in (
  "C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*"
) do set "theFolder=%%~fa\Data\Config"

echo %theFolder%
```

You can only include a wildcard in the last element of the path.

To do what you need, you have to enumerate the `12.*` folders and select one. In this case the last folder matching the wildcard is selected (as the code in the `do` clause is executed, the variable is overwritten)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@echo off

For /D %%D in ("C:\Users\All Users\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.*") Do (
    Set "Dir=%%~fD\Data\Config"
)

If exist "%Dir%\SyLink.xm_" Del /q %Dir%\SyLink.xm_"
Ren "%Dir%\SyLink.xml" sylink.xm_bak
Del /q "%Dir%\SyLink.xml"

echo.
echo Copying new SyLink.xml
echo.
copy C:\SyLink.xml "%Dir%"


echo.
echo Deleting temp files
Del /q "c:\SyLink.xml"
```

**/D** switch find for folders.

**%%~fD** gets full path from folder.